# pypark extracted nested JSON array not working as espected

Tags: arrays, json, dataframe, pyspark, nested

I am trying to read nested json, but the result is not what is expected according to what is indicated in many places I search previsly for.

**json:**

```
{'Folders': 
[
    {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Surveys'},
    {'Id': 44, 'Name': 'EERM - Evaluaci\xf3n de Proveedores'},
    {'Id': 8, 'Name': 'Encuesta para demo'},
    {'Id': 9, 'Name': 'RAS-DataAnalytics'},
    {'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Voxco Training'},
    {'Id': 10, 'Name': 'Cliente 1'},
    {'Id': 13, 'Name': 'Demo'},
    {'Id': 28, 'Name': 'Demo 6'},
    {'Id': 11, 'Name': 'A\xf1o 1'},
    {'Id': 46, 'Name': 'Proveedores de Bienes o Productos'},
    {'Id': 45, 'Name': 'Proveedores de Servicios'}
]
```

}

**Schema:**

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Folders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

**Select:** *What I get:*

```
>>> df.select("Folders.Id").show()
+--------------------+
|                  Id|
+--------------------+
|[1, 44, 8, 9, 2, ...|
+--------------------+
```

**What I Expect:**

```
+------+
|    Id|
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
| 44   |
+------+
| 8    |
+------+
| ...  |
+------+
```

I am using pyspark 2.4 and python 2.7
I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Folders` is an array of 1 element, all the values of it will be inferred as a single row.

To explode it to the multiple row, try this-

```scala
p = df.selectExpr("inline_outer(Folders)")
p.select("id").show()
+------+
|    Id|
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
| 44   |
+------+
| 8    |
+------+
| ...  |
+------+
```

Comment: This is great!, this works with all the fields at once.. nice.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the pyspark explode function is what you are looking for.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

js = [{'Folders': 
[
    {'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Surveys'},
    {'Id': 44, 'Name': 'EERM - Evaluaci\xf3n de Proveedores'},
    {'Id': 8, 'Name': 'Encuesta para demo'},
    {'Id': 9, 'Name': 'RAS-DataAnalytics'},
    {'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Voxco Training'},
    {'Id': 10, 'Name': 'Cliente 1'},
    {'Id': 13, 'Name': 'Demo'},
    {'Id': 28, 'Name': 'Demo 6'},
    {'Id': 11, 'Name': 'A\xf1o 1'},
    {'Id': 46, 'Name': 'Proveedores de Bienes o Productos'},
    {'Id': 45, 'Name': 'Proveedores de Servicios'}
]
}]

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(js))
df = df.select(explode(col("Folders")).alias("Folders"))
df.select("Folders.Id").show()
```

Returns the following:

```
+---+
| Id|
+---+
|  1|
| 44|
|  8|
|  9|
|  2|
| 10|
| 13|
| 28|
| 11|
| 46|
| 45|
+---+
```